# Java Inetaddress getallbyname error

Tags: java, inetaddress

I am using Java InetAddress to find if the current internet connection can resolve an address via DNS. However if I put in a random address (One that definitely dose not exist on the internet) I still get an IP back, can anyone explain why this is the case?

Code I am Using:

```
hosts = InetAddress.getAllByName(site.getSite());
            for(InetAddress host : hosts) {
                System.out.println(result_pref+"Ok "+ host);
            }
```

Output by command prompt:
Testing DNS Host: www.goooglelsdkfjsdlkfjsdklj.com
 - Result: Ok www.goooglelsdkfjsdlkfjsdklj.com/67.215.65.132

Thanks in advance

Comment: This IP points to a `404 Not found` page.

Answer (score 0):

67.215.65.132 address point to the webpage Hosted by the DNS server (the open you are using) in this case OpenDNS. THis simply means 404-Page Not found